Tag synonym requests related to "prf", "prp", and "prg"…
I would like to suggest…

the "prf" tag to be linked to the "pseudo-random-function" tag, as both are synonyms.
the "prg" tag to be linked to the "random-number-generator" tag, as both are synonyms (just like the already linked-up "prng" tag).
to create the non-existing "pseudo-random-permutation" tag, and link it up as a synonym to the existing "prp" tag.


I merged the prf tag into the pseudo-random-function tag (which affected 5 questions and created the synonym prf → pseudo-random-function.
I also merged the prp tag into the pseudo-random-permutation tag (which changed the tag on one question, and created the second tag and the synonym relation. Please note that there is only one question with this new tag now, so unless more relevant questions are found (or asked) and tagged by users, it is going to be deleted by some automatic tag cleanup process at some point.
I didn't do anything about prg and random-number-generator yet, as there also is the pseudo-random-generator tag. Should this be merged too, or might there be a significant (and relevant) difference between both?

Thanks for the first two. Hmmm, good question about [prg]. I've honestly been thinking about that one too. Personally, I'm not sure if there are many "pseudo-random-generators" out there (in the crypto-field) that return something else than numbers. If they return numbers, they would be "random-number-generators". Might indeed be worth discussing separately if [pseudo-random-generator] and [random-number-generator] describe the same thing or if it makes sense to keep those separate… and handle [prg] after that.

I was more thinking about the difference between pseudo and non-pseudo (i.e. true) random (number|bit|string) generators.

In that case, PRG would indeed fit Pseudo-Random-Generator without any doubt. PRG could include non-pseudo/hardware RNGs. (little facepalm moment for me there) Good thing you've got a sharp eye and noticed that! [+1]

PRG and Pseudo-random-generator should certainly be merged, but the RNG vrs PRG probably is a different discussion.

PRG and PRNG feel different to me. Actually, I see PRGs as generating bits (i.e. PRBGs) whereas PRNGs generate actual numbers. Even though you can use a PRG as a PRNG, they still feel different, to me at least... I think we should do prg -> pseudo-random-generator, rng -> random-number-generator, and prng -> pseudo-random-number-generator (?). Are we even interested in the distinction between PRNGs and CSPRNGs on this site (in a tag sense)? I feel like the answer is no; if that's the case, maybe have csprng -> pseudo-random-number-generator, ... perhaps?

I'm a little unclear how the synonyms would be two-way: as I understood it they acted as a rewrite rule taking A->B.
Anyway, it seems that the site standard is for the tag to have the full name? As such I agree that the new tag should be created, with 'prp' set as a synonym for it.

Please don't be confused by my (indeed somewhat unclear) wording, since you're correct about the “A->B” linkage etc. To avoid related confusion, I've edited my request and removed the "vice-versa" part.  [+1] and thanks for the heads-up on that one.
